# Is there an update repository for Python3.11 for Ubuntu 22.10?

Tags: updates, repository, python3

I recently upgraded to 22.10. Did "SUDO APT UPDATE and SUDO APT UPGRADE Python3," which updated to Python3.11. NO PROBLEM. Everything is fine.  I do, though, get the following errors when running software updater:
For the 'Nightly' updates -
"The repository https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/nightly/ubuntu kinetic Release does not have a Release file."
--- and ---
For the regular updates -
"The repository https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file"

The repository has the jammy release, but not the kinetic release. Is there a separate repository for "kinetic release?" or will deadsnakes simply add the release files to the above mentioned repository?

Thank you.

Comment: One assumes you are asking about doing this in some kind of disposable virtual environment. Because altering the version of python *outside* a virtual environment will break your system very, very badly.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a VERY SPECIFIC reason to attempt replacing the provided Python (as updated by `apt` or `apt-get`) you better not tamper with Ubuntu's standard Python (see it as **deeply embedded** into system update handling for one thing).
To replace it I believe you need to be experienced with how Python is used in Ubuntu.

Look into creating a virtual environment for anything else, it is a fairly easy thing to deal with.